# Printing python lists inside dictionary vertically

Tags: python, dictionary

```
output_dictionary = {
    "inputs": [3,5,10],
    "squared": [9,25,100],
    "cubed": [27,125,1000],
}

print('Number\tSquare\tCube')

for key, value in output_dictionary.items():
    # for num in value:
    #     print(num, end="\t")
    # print()
    for i in range(3):
        print(value[i], end="\t")
    print()
```

I want to print the output in this way

```
Number  Square  Cube
3       9       27
5       25      125
10      100     1000
```

I tried several methods but can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a list vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289068/how-to-display-a-list-vertically)

Comment: just switch position of these two :`for i in range(3):` and `for key, value in output_dictionary.items():`

Comment: on a jupyter notebook, the code in the question is producing the desired output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
output_dictionary = {
    "inputs": [3,5,10],
    "squared": [9,25,100],
    "cubed": [27,125,1000],
}

headers = ["Number", "Square", "Cube"]
values = output_dictionary.values()

row_format ="{:>10}" * (len(headers) + 1)
print(row_format.format("", *headers))

for value, row in zip(headers, values):
    print(row_format.format("", *row))
```

Will produce:

```
  Number   Square     Cube
    3         5        10
    9        25        100
    27       125       1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, in line with Federer's remark.

```
o = {
    "inputs": [3,5,10],
    "squared": [9,25,100],
    "cubed": [27,125,1000],
}

print('Number\tSquare\tCube')

for i in range(3):
    print(f'{o["inputs"][i]}\t {o["squared"][i]}\t {o["cubed"][i]}')
print()
```

Comment: This is much simpler and I understood the logic very well Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Number   Square  Cube')

for count in range(3):
    for i in output_dictionary:
        print(output_dictionary[i][count], end="\t")
    print()
```

> I finally figured it out. The printing loop comes like this. Thanks,
> everyone for the help!